# Trabajo simultáneo en Excel

Tags: vba

Estoy ejecutando una aplicación en VBA en un libro Excel y, mientras tanto, quiero trabajar con otro libro simultánemanete. ¿Es posible?

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Sí, claro que se puede hacer, pero tendrás que ser un poco más concreto si quieres que te ayudemos.

Comment: Tienes que abrir excel de nuevo para poder trabajar mientras tienes una macro funcionando de fondo. No obstante... Una macro no debería quitarte tanto tiempo como para necesitar hacer eso.

Comment: Tengo un libro el cual, al ser abierto, ejecuta una aplicación realizada en VBA de manera que, al salir de la aplicación, se cierra dicha aplicación y el propio Excel. Mientras se está ejecutando dicha "aplicación", puedo abrir otros libros de Excel, pero no puedo realizar ninguna operación con ellos. Por ejemplo, no puedo filtrar, ni modificar datos.

Answer (score 0):

para lo que deseas hacer, la tecnica mas usada es crear un userform, con el sub a ejecutar y al invocarlo agrega la instruccion modeless,

```
FormularioConCodigo.show vbmodeless
```

de esa forma el codigo se ejecutara directamente en el formulario, permitiendo usar la aplicacion excel como tal (con algunas limitaciones)

[ShowModal property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property)